# Command line at bootup?

Tags: boot, command-line

I'm a new user of ubuntu and unfortunatly I don't have a mouse at the moment, so I use the neat "mouse over keypad" functionality.

It's all great but very slow so I managed to find some sort of magic terminal command line :

Install xkbset

```
sudo apt-get install xkbset
```

Open a terminal and run

```
watch -n 1 xkbset ma 60 10 10 5 10
```

My problem is I would very much like this command to be executed at each boot of the system, can you point me to any documentation allowing me to do that ? If it's a trivial thing could you explain to me the few steps ?

Thanks again for your answers =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu (and all of its derivatives with a desktop environment) have a GUI tool for adding applications to startup.

It should be named "Startup" or something like that. Search in the Dash or Launcher or whatever your desktop environment has.

(You might want to use [this](https://youtu.be/8F9n8uef_pY) video tutorial.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ! I take note on the startup folder but I still need to find a way to use the command as some sort of executable.

I guess I need to put the raw command in a file with a specific extension but i have no clue which one it is ( the Terminal console is new to me and I have no clue what this language is )

Comment: If you use the GUI tool (Startup Applications), just put click 'Add', then in the 'Command:' filed type in the command you use. P.S. If you *really* want to use the startup folder, Create a file like so: `filename.sh` and in it, put in the command and save. Also mark file as executable (Done through right click on file->Properties->Permissions, or the CLI: `chmod +x /path/to/filename.sh`).

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple.  The process is adding a script, making it executable, and then putting it into the startup.

Assuming you're in your home folder. (cd ~)

```
touch xbdset-startup.sh
nano xbdset-startup.sh
```

Inset the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
watch -n 1 xkbset ma 60 10 10 5 10
```

Save the file, set the permissions.

```
chmod +x xbdset-startup.sh
```

Add the full path to your startup

Settings->Desktop->Session and Startup

```
/home/user/xbdset-startup.sh
```